# how to initialize a class?

Tags: python, django

please help set the initial value for CATEGORY_CHOICES through __ init__. 
I have a model.py class:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Anekdots(models.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
                            (u'red', u'red'),
                            (u'blue', u'blue'),
                            (u'magenta', u'magenta'),
                            (u'green', u'green'),
                            (u'yellow', u'yellow'),
        )

    body = models.TextField(max_length=700)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

but after trying to run python manage.py syncdb I get the following error:

```
NameError: name 'CATEGORY_CHOICES' is not defined
```

ps
**ps I need to initialize it through CATEGORY_CHOICES *init* (self):**

Comment: You need to define  `CATEGORY_CHOICES` at outside of class.

Comment: From django docs: _But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need to do it inside the `__init__` ?

Example code extracted from django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/db/models/

```
class Person(models.Model):
    SHIRT_SIZES = (
        ('S', 'Small'),
        ('M', 'Medium'),
        ('L', 'Large'),
    )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    shirt_size = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SHIRT_SIZES)
```

In your case, It should be:

```
class Anekdots(models.Model):
    CATEGORY_CHOICES = (
                            (u'red', u'red'),
                            (u'blue', u'blue'),
                            (u'magenta', u'magenta'),
                            (u'green', u'green'),
                            (u'yellow', u'yellow'),
    )

    body = models.TextField(max_length=700)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES)
```

**EDIT**: (Based on comments) If the category records are dynamic, you can init them using an init them with: `CATEGORY_CHOICES = Categories.get_all_entries()`

However, if the values are got from DB, you should consider to add a FK and let django model to do the job. I mean (also extracted from django doc):

> Finally, note that choices can be any iterable object – not necessarily a list or tuple. This lets you construct choices dynamically. But if you find yourself hacking choices to be dynamic, you’re probably better off using a proper database table with a ForeignKey. choices is meant for static data that doesn’t change much, if ever.

Comment: I need to get a set of categories from another object. something like this: 
Category.get_all_entries (). and put them in CATEGORY_CHOICES

Comment: @Sergey, Why don't you put simply `CATEGORY_CHOICES = Categories.get_all_entries()` ? At class scope.